# Size of Progress Bar doesn't change

Tags: android, xml, progress-bar

I want to place my ProgressBar in my LinearLayout:

```
<style name="MyProgressBar" parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.ProgressBar.Horizontal">
            <item name="android:progressBackgroundTint">#69f0ae</item>
            <item name="android:progressTint">#b71c1c</item>
            <item name="android:layout_width">match_parent</item>
            <item name="android:layout_height">@dimen/dp_2</item>
        </style>
```

but this line of code doesn't work correctly:

```
<item name="android:layout_width">match_parent</item>
```

Size does not change.

But if i write smth like this my size is changing:

```
<item name="android:minWidth">200dp</item>
```

Comment: I think match_parent works only in the context of a layout where a parent view is defined. When you use the attributes relative to size in styles a numeric value is expected. I'm only commenting that as I can't find the documentation to support my assumption.

Comment: You should make dimens file.You can declare match_parent in dimens file and then call here in style.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try creating a style then applying it your progress bar in layout should look like this.

I don't think you need to set your layout width and height in style.

```
 <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/progressBar"
        style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal" , <- Replace with custom style here.
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/progressBarHeight"
        android:indeterminate="true" />
```

Comment: Glad this helped.